# Not able to see sdk manager tool in Eclipse Juno 4.2.1

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create my first Android application using Eclipse Juno 4.2.1.

I installed Android from this link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse but it seems to have an error.

I am not able to see the option "Android Project". I tried using the other available option called "Android Application Project". When I try to open this it shows me an error:

> "Your tools information needs to be out of date(Or not yet installed).
>   Please update android sdk tools"..

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 18):

For getting sdk manager tool options in Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 Simple steps.

Window---->Customize Perspective--->Command Groups Availability

And then Simply check Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering how to get it back up there, hasn't been an issue for me yet but i like that little green guy up there...

Answer (score 2):

Please install the ADT plugin from this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) or if you already have it then update the ADT plug in using the normal eclipse update flow:

Updating the ADT Plugin

To update the ADT plugin to the latest version, follow these steps:

1. Select Help > Check for Update ...
2. If any update for ADT or Android tools is available, select and install.

Answer (score 0):

1> Go to install new software in help menue of eclipse and get ADT plugin from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

2> Go to android sdk manager in windows tab of eclipse.

3> Give the path of the downloaded sdk . Download it from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

4> Update the android sdk tools to revision 20

5> Update the android sdk platform tools to revision 12

6> First remove the android support lib in extras and then update it to the latest available revision

7> Restart eclipse.